# Action<T> and non-parametric methods

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I'm using Action for the retry action method called later in another module. Signature of the method using this Action is following

```
void ShowWarningMessageDialog<T>(string infoMessage, Action<T> retryAction, T parameter);
```

In some cases I need send retry method without parameter and of course it is not possible.  I tried some ugly solution like this (parameter is only fake and is not used in method)

```
public void Authorize(object parameter = null)
```

Another option is to define two methods like following, but I don't like this too

```
void ShowWarningMessageDialog<T>(string infoMessage, Action<T> retryAction, T parameter);
void ShowWarningMessageDialog(string infoMessage, Action retryAction);
```

Do you have some pattern or advice how to deal with it?

Comment: Is there a reason why you think the sensible solution -- have two methods for two type signatures-- is bad?

Comment: I think it is not so bad, but both of `ShowWarningMessageDialog` do the same. They send `retryAction` to MessageDialog that calls it if user wants. As for me, it smells with code duplication.

Comment: This should be modeled in a way that is expressive. If 'retryactions' encapsulate behaviour that goes beyond a simple delegate ShowWarningMessageDialog should be fed a well designed IRetryAction interface for extensibility. What if you need to pass more then one parameter in the future?

Comment: Solution is here : `ShowWarningMessageDialog("hello world", 
    () => SomeMethod(someParameter1,someParameter2));`. I think, it is sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just send a parameterless delegate (`Action`) and use a lambda to close over any variables that the function may or may not need.  So the signature (of the sole overload) would become:

```
void ShowWarningMessageDialog<T>(string infoMessage, Action retryAction)
```

And if you had a parameter (or any number of them) you would call the method like so:

```
ShowWarningMessageDialog("hello world", 
    () => someInstance.SomeMethod(someParameter));
```

Answer (score 7):

Regarding your comment:

> both of `ShowWarningMessageDialog` do the same. They send `retryAction` to `MessageDialog` that calls it if user wants. As for me, it smells with code duplication.

Then eliminate the duplication. I would write *three* methods, like this:

```
void ShowWarningMessageDialog<T>(
    string infoMessage, 
    Action<T> retryAction, 
    T parameter)
{
    // Do no work here; defer to other method.
    ShowWarningMessageDialog(infoMessage, ()=>{retryAction(parameter);});
}
void ShowWarningMessageDialog<T>(
    string infoMessage, 
    Action<T> retryAction)
{
    // Do no work here; defer to other method.
    ShowWarningMessageDialog(infoMessage, retryAction, default(T));
}
void ShowWarningMessageDialog(
    string infoMessage, 
    Action retryAction)
{
    // Actually do the work here. 
}
```

Now you have all the signatures you could possibly need, and the actual code is only in one place.